com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found?
I'm trying to update a cell in Google Sheets table. I'm certain that the sheetid, credentials, page in table ("Names"), and cell ("B2") are all correct.
Stacktrace:
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
PUT https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1OF8UZnI8AZ0ExmTxXdq7NmXCQo_8dg4pTV6Z8e4KQKQ/values/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%821!B2?valueInputOption=RAW
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Requested entity was not found.",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "Requested entity was not found.",
  "status" : "NOT_FOUND"
}

Code:
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.ValueRange;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class GoogleSheets {

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = ".....";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = ".......";
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

    private Sheets sheetsService;

    public GoogleSheets() throws Exception {
        final com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        this.sheetsService = new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    private Credential getCredentials(final com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws Exception {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }

    public void updateCellValue(String spreadsheetId, String range, String value) {
        try {
            ValueRange body = new ValueRange().setValues(
                    Collections.singletonList(Collections.singletonList(value))
            );
            sheetsService.spreadsheets().values()
                    .update(spreadsheetId, range, body)
                    .setValueInputOption("RAW")
                    .execute();
            System.out.println("Cell updated: " + range + " with value: " + value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            GoogleSheets service = new GoogleSheets();
            service.updateCellValue("1OF8UZnI8AZ0ExmTxXdq7NmXCQo_8dg4pTV6Z8e4KQKQ", "Names!B2", "123");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

Why am I getting a 404 response here?

You had this error:
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Requested entity was not found.",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "Requested entity was not found.",
  "status" : "NOT_FOUND"
}

The errors you can get at this "global" level include:

404 - if the spreadsheetId does not identify an actual spreadsheet
403 - if the spreadsheetId identifies an actual spreadsheet, but you don't have permission
400 - if the spreadsheetId identifies an actual spreadsheet, but the Sheet Name is wrong, and other reasons

Otherwise your code looks correct.

There was a problem with a token, as i understood different APIs (i was using Drive API and Sheets API) need different tokens, so when you authorize u need to delete previous token or create new one

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
